# Multilevel inheritance constructor in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor

Is there a way in C# to call the grandfather's constructor? Let's say I have:

```
public class A
{
   public A(parameterX x)
   {
      doSomething();
   }
}

public class B : A
{
   public B(parameterX x) : base(x)
   {
      doSomethingElse();
   }
}
```

And then I have:

```
public class C : B
{
}
```

And I want the constructor in C to call the constructor in A, what can I use for this?
Is there something like:

```
public C(parameterX x) : base : base(x)
```

Or how can I just call the constructor in A from C?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not have the B constructor call A, so when C is called, A gets called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call a grandparent class' constructor.
However, you don't need to either, since the base class already does.

When you write `public C(parameterX x) : base(x)`, it will call `B(x)`, which will in turn call `A(x)`.

In general, since your base class' constructor will always call its base constructor (your grandparent), it wouldn't make sense to be able to explicitly call the grandparent  constructor, since that would end up constructing it twice.

Comment: I know, but the problem is a bit more complicated than what I wrote here, the B constructor takes a parameter from class foo, and the C constructor takes a parameter from class bar. Foo and bar are different but both have class D as a parent. Then class A constructor takes a parameter of either one since it's using templating. So I can't go through B, but A would work ok with my parameter.

Comment: No. You must always call a (direct-)base class constructor.  You cannot have a non-constructed class.  Consider adding a `protected` constructor to `B`.  Also, that sounds like a bad design; consider refactoring it.

Comment: I might add the protected constructor, the design is not the best, I'm trying to integrate into an existing environment with kind of a hack that will save me tons of work. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although I don't really understand what is that you are trying to do and you probably can come up with a better actual design, you can probably achieve what you need by adding another constructor in B that takes the Bar parameter as A, but do nothing in it simply calling A(Bar) constructor, that way when you do C(bar) : base(bar) it will go to B and then to A. Ugly as hell.

Comment: I might do this, I know is a bad design, just trying to save me tons of work for now.